# How to understand the `drop` in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

From the [documentation for `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

> It is a drop in replacement with better behavior in many situations.

I don't understand the `drop` meaning in the paragraph. who can explain it for me?

Comment: Maybe, a technical *jargon!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that *drop in* is slightly mis-punctuated, and drop does not stand on its own.  The software is not a *"drop (in replacement)"* but rather a *"(drop-in) replacement."*

It is a replacement.  What type of replacement?  A drop-in replacement.

*Drop-in* as an adjective can mean several things.  Definition #4 at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drop-in) is close in meaning to how it is being used here:

> *drop-in*  - requiring only insertion to be ready for use:>

If two pieces of software perform more or less the same task, but go about it with different approaches, interface and/or APIs, then one is a replacement for the other, but neither is a *drop-in* replacement for the other.  Think `Outlook` and `Gmail`.  Both serve essentially the same purpose, but they accomplish it very differently.

By contrast, `mpg123` and `mpg321` do the same thing, are about the same size, and take almost identical command line arguments.  `mpg321` is a *drop-in* replacement for `mpg123`